# Firebase Magic Links not passing deep linked data after app installation - Works when app is already installed

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm currently implementing Firebase Magic Links for my iOS React Native app and encountering an issue with deep linked data after app installation. Here's the setup and the specific issue I'm facing:

1. I have integrated Firebase into my React Native app using the `@react-native-firebase` package.
2. Firebase Dynamic Links are properly configured in my Firebase project settings.
3. I'm using the `firebase.dynamicLinks()` module to handle the magic link functionality.
4. When a user receives a magic link email and taps on it, it successfully opens the App Store for app installation.
5. However, after the app is installed, the deep linked data is not available in the app. It seems like the deep linked data is not passed to the app during the installation process.

**Additional Information:**

- If the magic link is opened when the app is already installed on the device, it successfully opens the app and includes the deep linked data.
- I have verified that my app's bundle ID is correctly configured in Firebase, and I have associated the correct domains in the Firebase Dynamic Links settings.
- The `apple-app-site-association` file is correctly hosted on my server and is accessible.
- I have tested the deep linking functionality separately using a custom URL scheme, and it works as expected both before and after app installation.
- I have verified that my app's Info.plist file includes the necessary `CFBundleURLTypes` and `CFBundleURLSchemes` entries.

I'm seeking insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to ensure that the deep linked data is passed to the app after installation via the Firebase Magic Links. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on what might be causing this behavior? Are there any additional configuration steps or modifications that I need to make to ensure the deep linked data is available after app installation? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!